# Unityengine.VR assembly reference issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am new to Unity development with visual studio.

I have installed 5.4.2 version and opened one project and getting following error.

Assets/Holograms/Support/Spatial Mapping/SpatialMapping.cs(2,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `WSA' does not exist in the namespace`UnityEngine.VR'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the normal Unity version to build for Hololens. Native Hololens support will lileky be in Unity 5.5 release. Right now, you need *Unity HoloLens Technical Preview* to build for Hololens. You can get that from [here](https://unity3d.com/partners/microsoft/hololens).

For other requirements for building Hololens app in Unity, you can check [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/install_the_tools?Ocid=Hololens%20-%20Education_Social_TWITTER_HoloLens_20160330_413089651).